# Lake Bathymetry Open Data

Tags: data-request, data.gov, environment

I would like to know if anyone knows a good open source where I can get Lake bathymetry raster. I need to extract depth values from it.

Comment: Are you looking for bathymetry data for a specific body of water? all USA bodies of water?

Comment: I needed some Lake bathy info regarding African lakes..